# Including a common html header in all pages in website of 20 pages (with active class)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Assume I have 20 navbar items, each one linking to a different               page on my website. And on each page those 20 items remain the same. To avoid copy-pasting across all .html files, other solutions have suggested doing this with php. But how would I make the active menu item lit white for example? I want to refrain from copy-pasting the header across to all the .html files, because if I want to add one more navbar item, I will have to manually add it to all .html files.

There must be a simple solution **with** an active item for the active page.

========EDIT========

Naomik, your javascript solution looks most promising, although I currently can't get it to work (**see second edit below**).

My navbar is defined in nav.html:

```html
<nav id="nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div>
    <ul id="navigation" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
      <li class="active"><a href="about.html" >About</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.html" >Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="pricing.html" >Pricing</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And this is one of the three html pages (about.html). I use JS to load in the nav.html file. The JS snippet before the closing body tag is the one provided by naomik.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.get("nav.html", function(data){
    $("#nav-placeholder").replaceWith(data);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- *** NAVBAR *** -->
<div id="nav-placeholder"></div>
<!-- *** MAIN TEXT *** -->
<h1>ABOUT</h1>
<script>
  function removeQueryString(url) {
    return url.split('?')[0]
  }
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), function(elem) {
    if (removeQueryString(elem.href) === removeQueryString(window.location.href))
      elem.classList.add('is-active')
    else
      elem.classList.remove('is-active')
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

============EDIT==========

Although Naomik's solution leads to a [flashing website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220226/website-flashes-between-loads) on every load of a page. I have therefore applied Relisora's solution.

Thanks

Comment: It will help if you posted some snippet of navbar html code.

Comment: Thanks Prashank. I have posted some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this this with PHP. You can add a little JavaScript to the end of your HTML before the closing `</body>` tag

> **Notice**: Clicking the links in the snippet preview will **not** work for obvious reason. They are only there to show you that the correct link will highlight.
>
> StackOverflow Code Snippets run from the URL `http:stacksnippets.net/js`. Knowing this, we can verify that our code works by making sure any `href="/js"` links get the `is-active` class.

After reading that notice above, click the **Run code snippet** button below

```css
code {
  font-family: monospace;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.is-active {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<h4>
  This window is currently at url:<br>
  <code>http://stacksnippets.net/js</code>
</h4>

<a href="/js">js</a>
<a href="/html">html</a>
<a href="/php">php</a>

<p>The <b>js</b> link above gets the is-active CSS class because it matches the window's current pathname</p>
<script>
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), function(elem) {
    if (elem.pathname === window.location.pathname)
      elem.classList.add('is-active')
    else
      elem.classList.remove('is-active')
  })
</script>
```

Notice that each `a` element in the original HTML does not have any `class` attribute. After the JS runs, notice that **only** the `<a href="/js">js</a>` link will automatically be given the `is-active` CSS class.

---

Here's a jQuery solution for you.

```css
code {
  font-family: monospace;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.is-active {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>
  This window is currently at url:<br>
  <code>http://stacksnippets.net/js</code>
</h4>

<a href="/js">js</a>
<a href="/html">html</a>
<a href="/php">php</a>

<p>The <b>js</b> link above gets the is-active CSS class because it matches the window's current pathname</p>
<script>
  function highlightActiveLinks() {
    $('a').filter(function(idx, elem) {
      return elem.pathname === window.location.pathname
    }).addClass('is-active')
  }
  
  highlightActiveLinks()
</script>
```

In yours, you will need this tho. This can't be demo'd in the SO snippet, sorry.

```
$.get('nav.html', function(data) {
  // ...
  highlightActiveLinks()
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I have expanded the question as a follow up to this response.

Comment: @OliverAngelil I see your updated question. I've provided a working proof in my answer. Hopefully this will help.

Comment: Thanks! However I still don't know how to solve my problem with this answer, because in my case I have the navbar in a separate html file which is loaded using a short javascript snippet (see my lines before the end head tag).

Comment: @OliverAngelil you'll have to wrap my code inside of a function, perhaps `function highlightActiveLinks() { /* my code here */ }` and then call that function within the load handler of the `$.get` call. `$.get('nav.html', function(data) { ... highlightActiveLinks(); })`.

Comment: @OliverAngelil, I've updated my answer with a jQuery example too

Comment: Thanks. I've implemented it on my website (http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~oangelil/rehtmlproblemnavbaractive/about.html). Now the entire page seems to flash (safari seems better than chrome) when a new navbar icon is clicked. Perhaps you know of a solution.. otherwise I'll eventually manage...

Comment: Might you know why it flashes? I have written a new post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220226/website-flashes-between-loads?noredirect=1#comment63863207_38220226

Comment: Could you elaborate as to why one should not use php in your answer? Relisora's solution seems to work best.

Comment: Well it's pretty silly to load the template pieces with JavaScript unless you don't plan on doing any page reloading at all. You can use `require 'nav.php';` on the PHP side of things and still use JavaScript for adding the `is-active` class. The reason I'd use JS instead of PHP for this is because of how easy it is to do *site-wide* using JS. With like 4 lines of JS you can solve the problem once and be done with it. With PHP you have to add the logic to *every* single `echo <a href...>` and every one that you add in the future.

Comment: The problem you have is probably a little bit bigger than you're imagining it. There's a lot that goes into designing a good way to load templates and provide a nice end user experience.

Comment: Cool. Using php to load the pages and JS to change active / inactive menu items seems to be the simplest solution that works!

Answer (score 2):

You first want to give each of your 20 pages a name ( or a number ).

On each page, write the page name

```
<?php $page_name = "index" ?>
```

Then you import your navbar

```
<?php include 'navbar.php'; ?>
```

Now in your navbar.php you want to check on what `$page_name` you are

```
<?php if ($page_name == 'index') {echo ' id="active"';} ?>
```

And you do that for each page you have.

Now you'll just want to have `#active {}` in your CSS to determine the style, and your current page will show with active style.

**Edit :**

Now that we can write `id="active"`, we want it to be in `li`so we can use the class :

```
<li<?php if ($page_name == 'index') {echo ' id="active"';} ?>>Home page</li>
```

Don't forget to add the link :

```
<li<?php if ($page_name == 'index') {echo ' id="active"';} ?>><a href="#" >Home page</a></li>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I did the following: 1) rename all the html file endings to .php 2) wrote the page name on each page 3) import the navbar.php on each page 4) I check what page I'm on. However the code (if statement) you provided does not seem to work, in particular [echo ' id="active"'] simply writes id="active" to the screen rather than defining the id tag. 5) I defined #active in my .css

Comment: yes, this is what the code is supposed to do. Now that we can write id="active" somewhere, we want it to be in the li. I'll edit my answer with the context

Answer (score 1):

make a .html file with just the navbar and include it in an iframe

```
<iframe src="navbar.html"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample php code that iterates through an array of paths and constructs a menu.

If the function is given an active path (current path) as an input it compares to each path and if they match it adds a class to the link.

I've hard coded an active path to demonstrate the output.

You can bundle all this up into a file called something like nav.php and include it on each page.

```
<?php
     include 'includes/nav.php';
?>
```

nav.php:

```
<?php

$paths = array(
    '/foo/',
    '/foo/bar/',
    '/foo/baz/',
    );

function nav($paths, $active_path = null) {
    $o = '';
    foreach($paths as $path) {
        $a_class = $active_path == $path ? 'active' : '';
        $o .= "<a class='$a_class' href='$path'>$path</a><br />\n";
    }

    return $o;
}

$active_path = strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '?');
$active_path    = '/foo/bar/';
?>
<?php echo nav($paths, $active_path); ?>
```

Output:

```
<a class='' href='/foo/'>/foo/</a><br />
<a class='active' href='/foo/bar/'>/foo/bar/</a><br />
<a class='' href='/foo/baz/'>/foo/baz/</a><br />
```

Personally however I prefer adding the active class with javascript.  In which case you can just construct a html snippet and take advantage of the php include, server side include, or js include to add the html to each page.

Comment: Hi Progrock, could you let me know how you add the active class with javascript. The code snippet in the question does not work. Thanks!

Comment: @OliverAngelil work with naomik's answer, if that's what you require. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38218049/3392762

Comment: @Proogrock. That's exactly what is in the code snippet in the question above. The issue is the same menu item remains active...

Comment: 'active' may not be the best descriptor, as links can have an 'active' state.

Answer (score 0):

for bootstrap

`<a class="nav-link <?php if ($page_name == 'index') {echo "active";} ?> href="index.php">Home</a>`

or in shorthand

```
<a class="nav-link <?php echo ($page_name == 'index') ? "active" : "";?> href="index.php">Home</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all rename the file name sample.html with sample.php

just use include syntax for php:

```
    <?php include("sample.php"); ?>
    or

    <?php require("sample.php");?>
```

Add this in all 20 pages after remove the code.

Hope this will helps!

Answer (score -1):

It can do by php.

1. First you create all pages as php files.
2. Create one file as nav_menu.php. In this page code all menu items.
3. In all pages instead menu codes include nav_menu.php
4. To give active class use`$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]` to check current url equals to particular url. If it is equal add class active.