# Website flashes between loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My [website](http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~oangelil/rehtmlproblemnavbaractive/pricing.html) flashes between loads. I've applied methods suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358087/flashing-between-page-loads) stackoverflow question, with no luck. Each of the three pages loads a [nav.html](http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~oangelil/rehtmlproblemnavbaractive/nav.html) file with:

```js
$.get("nav.html", function(data){
    $("#nav-placeholder").replaceWith(data);
});
```

Please view page source for the .html code. The website is built in such a way based on my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38217950/including-a-common-html-header-in-all-pages-in-website-of-20-pages-with-active): essentially I want the navbar items to be described in one file only (nav.html) so if I choose to make any changes to it, I only have to edit one file.

Comment: This FOUC is the main issue with putting include logic on the client side. Is there no way you can use a server side include? It would avoid the problem entirely, and save you network bandwidth.

Comment: I'm here from your last post. I suggest you to try my solution ( using PHP ) for your problem. I think that it will not flash anymore as it is loaded at the same time as the rest of your page. [link to my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38218059/6310279)

Comment: @Relisora Thanks. Although when I use php on my mac I cannot view the website locally — php only seems to work when it's up on a server.

Comment: @OliverAngelil You can use MAMP on mac to do a local server on your PC. It works very well

Comment: @Relisora Thanks for your suggestion. I replied on the other page.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing do do with the performance of the website/webserver.

It is because you load a new html file for each navigation point.

To solve this you would need to fetch via new content asynchronously and replace the existing content already loaded on the page. This is usually done via Javascript.
The steps would be

- 1) load the external html file via ajax
- 2) replace the current content with the new loaded data once it is there.

This also means that your url would never change. it would stay at .../about.html

Answer (score 0):

I've read somewhere that ng-cloak is usefull in this scenario but did not research into it....maybe it will be usefull for you to do some digging.
[ngCloak docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)